# Filter true values of nested JSON

Tags: typescript

I am trying to filter a JSON to only have the properties that have a value of true or a nested property of true.

Consider the following JSON

```
{
  "name": "xyz",
  "version": "50",
  "A": true,
  "B": {
    "type": ""
  },
  "C": {
    "D": true,
    "E": true
  },
  "I": true
}
```

I want to obtain the following result:

```
{
  "A": true,
  "C": {
    "D": true,
    "E": true
  },
  "I": true
}
```

An alternative to this result that I can also use is a non-nested version:

```
{
  "A": true,
  "D": true,
  "E": true,
  "I": true
}
```

If possible, I would like to have both functions.

I am trying the following function:

```js
function(response) {
  let result = {};
  for (const key in response) {
    const entry = response[key];
    if (entry == true) {
      result[key] = entry;
    }
  }
  return result;
}
```

With this being the return of the function:

```
{
  "A": true,
  "I": true
}
```

Comment: It's 2022 and time to learn about `let` and `const`. Let `var` go.

Comment: `entry == true` will coerce `entry` (so any truthy value will pass). If you want to check for `true`, use `entry === true`.

Comment: for entry === true also I am getting {A: true, I: true} only, I need all the true values like {A: true, D:true E: true, I: true}

Comment: Right, because `"C": { "D": true, "E": true }` does not equal `true`. You're only filtering the top level.

Comment: Are you expecting `{ "A": true, "C": { "D": true, "E": true }, "I": true }` or `{ "A": true, "D": true, "E": true, "I": true }`?

Comment: @DM can you give any examples related to this

Comment: like this: { "A": true, "C": { "D": true, "E": true }, "I": true } or { "A": true, "D": true, "E": true, "I": true }

Comment: Which one of those are you expecting? They require different answers.

Comment: please add the wanted result.

Comment: if possible can you pleas share those two 1. { "A": true, "C": { "D": true, "E": true }, "I": true } 2. { "A": true, "D": true, "E": true, "I": true }

Answer (score 1):

You could take a recursive approach and filter the level or the nested ones, if an object occurs.

```js
const
    filter = object => {
        const entries = Object
            .entries(object)
            .flatMap(([k, v]) => {
                const temp = v === true ||
                    v && typeof v === 'object' && filter(v);
                return temp
                    ? [[k, temp]]
                    : [];
            });
        return entries.length ? Object.fromEntries(entries) : undefined;
    },
    response = { name: "xyz", version: "50", A: true, B: { type: "" }, C: { D: true, E: true }, I: true };

console.log(filter(response));
```

Comment: fromEntries and flatMap have any alternative function

Comment: this answer did not working for me

Comment: @Abi.D, why? what goes wrong? do you need the same object reference?

Comment: like I am not able to use fromEnteries and flatMap, any alternatives for this: Property 'flatMap' does not exist on type '[string, unknown][] and this too Property 'fromEntries' does not exist on type 'ObjectConstructor'.